# Reading JSON Ajax response?

Tags: javascript

I have an ajax response from my server. Example below:

```
{"user_id":"93","status_message":"Cool Status","timestamp":"1305648702"}
```

I tried reading the response using:

```
var json = eval(response);
var userid = json.user_id;
```

The above does not seem to work though. Any ideas.

Comment: **Please provide more detail**.  Why doesn't it work? What happens? What's `response`?

Comment: The response is userid is undefined.

Comment: The response from my server is {"user_id":"93","status_message":"Cool Status","timestamp":"1305648702"}. Once the response is obtained, and eval'ed userid is undefined.

Comment: I would recommend using the JSON parser built-in as the answer below states.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the JSON parser that is built in to many browsers these days. If it's not available, you can use the [JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), which provides the same interface, as a fallback.

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
var userid = json.user_id;
```

Comment: And include https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js for other browsers to have it always just work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the `eval(response)` and just do:

```
var userid = response.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
var userid = json.user_id;
```